# Get list of directories and files in git repo using Python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to fetch all files and directories present in a git repo using Python and then parse through each directory to get details of files present under them.

Below is the piece of code I have been trying but it returns nothing. I am able to get branch details.

```
import git
import os
from git import Repo

Repo.clone_from(repo_url,local_path)
repo = git.Repo(local_path)
remote = repo.remote("origin")

for branches in remote.refs:
 //code to get a specific branch, say abc, using if condition

repo.git.checkout(abc)
os.listdir(local_path)
```

Comment: Which `git` library exactly are you trying to use? Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one example:

```
import git
import os

# Clone the repository
repo_url = "https://github.com/your_username/your_repository.git"
local_path = "path_to_local_clone"
git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, local_path)

# Switch to a specific branch
repo = git.Repo(local_path)
repo.git.checkout("master")

# List files and directories in the repository
contents = os.listdir(local_path)

for item in contents:
    item_path = os.path.join(local_path, item)

    if os.path.isfile(item_path):
        print(f"File: {item}")
    elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
        print(f"Directory: {item}")
```